# Routing error with angular.js and express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I am trying to do routing with angular.js around /parent root, which works if I'm using anchor links, etc (aka routing handled purely from angular. For instance, a link that has href of '/parent/createstudent' works. However, when I type this in the url bar or when I refresh it when it is already at that location, it generates an error since the backend route isn't done yet.

I thus tried a catchall route ('/parent/*') in express, but this is resulting in an error with all my js and css not being read. Does anyone know how to solve this?

My static file directory

```
public
  -> javascripts
      -> app.js
      -> angular.js
  -> stylesheets
  -> images
```

Error:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/parent/javascripts/jquery.js". home:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/parent/javascripts/angular.js". home:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/parent/javascripts/main.js". home:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Express

```
app.get('/parent', function(req, res) {
  res.render('main')
});
app.get('/parent/*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('main')
});
```

Angular routing (i declare the controllers in the view itself)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider.when('/parent/login', 
    {
      templateUrl: '../templates/login.html'
    }).
    when('/parent/home', 
    {
      templateUrl: '../templates/home.html'
    }).
    otherwise(
    {
      redirectTo: '/parent'
    })
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're serving your JS/CSS via `/parent` as well:

```
... http://localhost:3000/parent/javascripts/jquery.js
                         ^^^^^^^
```

So if you declare your routes *before* you declare the `express.static` middleware, your catch-all route will handle all JS/CSS requests.

You should use a setup similar to this:

```
// express.static() first...
app.use('/parent', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// ...followed by your catch-all route (only one needed)
app.get('/parent*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('main')
});
```

Comment: Hi robert, thank you for your answer. Currently I don't have a parent directory before my static files - does angular naturally assume I do because I'm serving from /parent?

Comment: @DanTang no, Angular doesn't, but I think your HTML looks something like this: `<script src="javascripts/angular.js"></script>`? (without a `/` in front of `javascripts/`). If so, your browser will load the JS files relative to the current page URL.

Comment: Ah got it, that makes sense. Sorry but could I ask one more question - I changed my javascripts to '/javascripts' and now it works sometimes. Like when i start with /parent, the links for /parent/home and /parent/login work, but once i refresh it, it goes straight to /parent (since I made it redirect to '/'), but when I click on the links (e.g. /parent/login), it immediately changes to /parent rather than /parent/login. Do you know how I can solve that?

Comment: @DanTang if you're at `/parent/home` and refresh, it should stay there because you have declared a route for that in Angular. I don't understand why it will redirect you back to `/parent`. Check your browsers' console log to see if Angular is generating any errors.

Comment: hmmm, I don't have any more angular errors, but it does redirect me back to parent (i think it could be because I defined otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})?

Answer (score 16):

This is a newly introduced "change of behavior" (or bug).

Try using the base tag :

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, Angular routes are also relative to the current URL, even when they start with a `/`?

Comment: When you start angular, it starts everything after the last / and use it as the base url - unless told otherwise :).

Comment: Thanks @Ven for the explanation. Anybody got a link to where this is documented?

Comment: Hey This resolve the problem of getting this error but after that I start getting 404 on the css library.